# Dynamically binding of overridden methods

Tags: c++, dynamic-binding, static-binding

I'm trying to understand when the compiler has, or not, all the information needed to decide statically or dynamically how to bind method calls to method definitions.

I read that in Java there is a rule that binds them statically when the method is overloaded and dynamically when it is overridden. I'm playing around with some C++ code and it's not clear to me how it works.

For example, if I have:

```
class A
{
    public:

    // virtual void p()
    void p() {
        cout << "A::p" << endl;
    }

    void q() {
        p();
    }
};

class B : public A
{
    public:

    void p() {
        cout << "B::p" << endl;
    }
};
```

a) When I do:

```
A a;
B b;

a.q();    // output: A::p
b.q();    // output: A::p
```

I assume the compiler (g++) binds statically `b.q()` to `A.q()` and `p()` (inside `A.q()`) to `A.p()`. `A.p()` is into the context of `A.q()`

b) But, **if I declare `A.p()` as virtual**, the output will be:

```
a.q();    // output: A::p
b.q();    // output: B::p
```

Here, I imagine that, `b.q()` is bound to `A.q()`, statically as did the previous scenario, but `p()` inside `A.q()` is bound to `B.p()`, that override `A.p()`.

If the rule were the same (that overriding is resolved dynamically), it would imply that the compiler does not have all the necessary information to do it statically.

Why can't the compiler bind the overridden version of the virtual method instead of deferring that decision to the runtime? Which is the lacking information here?

===> Edited <===

It was suggested not to mix Java and C++. I'm reading the Louden & Lambert book "Programming Languages" and the authors compare what bindings look like in both languages. That is the reason why I mentioned them. But, my question is more related to the need for dynamic linking, regardless of language. Why can't the compiler figure out based on the source code how to bind virtual or overridden methods?

Comment: Don't compare one language 1-1 to another. C++ doesn't have binding, it has virtual functions (dynamic). and templates (static/compile time). In this case  it should have been `virtual void p();` for class A and  `void p() override` for class B. And then to use polymorphism you would need (unique) pointers or references to the baseclass. https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/virtual-functions/

Comment: Please don't use both [Java] and [C++] for this question.  Pick one and if you need answer for both languages please post 2 questions, one for each language.

Comment: _"...Which is the lacking information here?.."_ when `A` is compiled the compiler has not seen `B` it may be in a different compilation unit and not seen until link time or not exist at all.  So the compiler can't do anything clever as it does not know that anything needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ uses virtual method tables to support dynamic dispatch.
An instance of a class contains a hidden pointer to a struct containing the function pointers
for the `virtual` methods for that class.

For a simple example:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    virtual void p();
};

void some_function(A* ap) {
    ap->p();
}
```

The compiler has no idea ahead of time what code the call to `ap->p();` will actually invoke.

`some_function` could be compiled into object code, sitting in a library or
linked to an executable, run and invoke `ap-p>();`, and execute code that
literally didn't exist at the time `some_function` was compiled.